# Android Studio Starting with e-sim

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, e-sim

I just got a job in telecommunication company and I am currently working on android application using Android Studio as an environment with Kotlin and Java as a programming languages.

They requested from me to review this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/euicc/EuiccManager.html#downloadSubscription(android.telephony.euicc.DownloadableSubscription,%20boolean,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and give them the inputs that I need from them to use it to start using e-sim in our application.

Note that my company is a carrier and service provider.

I don't know how to start with this or what to do, because I am new at developing mobile application, so I need tips or guides for how to do that, what I need and if there are some examples that would be better.

Comment: have look on this https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-overview

Comment: @NJ do i need to extend anything or just use the methods?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend manager class as written in the docs to set in your custom operations

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31849618)